# How to merge 2 objects such that both object properties are intact-Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to merge/concat 2 objects, such a way that currently i have:

```
var mergeObj = {};
var obj1 = { name: 'abd', id: 5454756, color: 'red' }
var obj2 = { name: 'abc1', id:387589, color: 'blue'}
```

Now if I merge it should be:

```
Object {obj1: Object, obj2: Object}
```

However I tried the following:

```
mergeObj = obj1.merge(obj2);
```

and it merges to one object, which is not what i'm looking for. I want to merge in such a way that the final object will have 2 fields: `obj1` and `obj2`.

Ex:

[image]

is it possible?? Any ideas?

thanks~

Comment: look at @adeneo's solution

Comment: Why not using an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this code

```
var mergeObj = {};

var obj1 = { name: 'abd', id: 5454756, color: 'red' }
var obj2 = { name: 'abc1', id:387589, color: 'blue'}


mergeObj.obj1=obj1;
mergeObj.obj2=obj2;
console.log(mergeObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj1 = { name: 'abd', id: 5454756, color: 'red' }
var obj2 = { name: 'abc1', id:387589, color: 'blue'}
var mergeObj = { obj1: obj1, obj2: obj2 };
```

In javascript everything is an object and a property can be any object, so you just need to create a new object with the properties of it set to the original objects.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj1 = {
    name1: 'abd',
    id: 5454756,
    color: 'red'
  }
  var obj2 = {
    name: 'abc1',
    id: 387589,
    color: 'blue'
  }

  $.extend(obj1, obj2);
  alert(obj2.name + "," + obj1.name);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's only two objects, you could quite simply add them together as a new object.

```
var obj1 = { name: 'abd', id: 5454756, color: 'red' },
    obj2 = { name: 'abc1', id:387589, color: 'blue'},
    objs = { obj1, obj2 };

console.log(obj1, obj2, objs);

// Output:
// Object {name: "abd", id: 5454756, color: "red"}
// Object {name: "abc1", id: 387589, color: "blue"}
// Object {obj1: Object, obj2: Object}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/o7jf5baa/

You can do it with more than two, I just mean it's simple enough without any complex functions or extra libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to be a duplicate of [jquery merge two objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130908/jquery-merge-two-objects).

The solution provided by adeneo is:

```
//merging two objects into new object
var new_object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```