# How to save the result of MySql query in variable using node-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

im trying to save the result of MySql query in variable using node-mysql model and node.js so i have this code:

```
connection.query("select * from ROOMS", function(err, rows){
if(err) {
    throw err;
} else {
    console.log(rows);
}
});
```

and the result is :

```
[ { idRooms: 1, Room_Name: 'dd' },
  { idRooms: 2, Room_Name: 'sad' } ]
```

so i need to store this results in variable so i try like this:

```
 var someVar = connection.query("select * from ROOMS", function(err, rows){
if(err) {
    throw err;
} else {
    return rows;
}
});

console.log(someVar);
```

but is not working thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well @Fadi, `connection.query` is async, which mean when your call your `console.log(someVar)`, `someVar` has not been set yet.

What you could do:

```
var someVar = [];

connection.query("select * from ROOMS", function(err, rows){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    setValue(rows);
  }
});

function setValue(value) {
  someVar = value;
  console.log(someVar);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks but another question if i don't store the result in varible how can i send it throw socket.io to the cline-side

Comment: @Fadi, you should read [this article](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks) about how to design your solution when building things in node.js. It's not that long and totally worth reading.

Comment: I am trying to return the someVar variable but get "Promise Pending" message. Any ideas?

Comment: its console out the data but it can't be sented as response, please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because network i/o is asynchronous and non-blocking in node.js. So any logic that comes afterwards that must execute only after the query has finished, you must place *inside* the query's callback. If you have many nested asynchronous operations you may look into using a module such as [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help better organize your asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to already given answers.

```
var **someVar** = connection.query( *sqlQuery*, *callback function( err , row , fields){}* )

console.log(**someVar**);
```

This construction will return in **someVar** information of this connection and his SQL query . It will not return values ​​from the query .

Values ​​from the query are located in the callback function ( err , row , fields)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer if you want to assign a variable to res.render

```
//before define the values
var tum_render = [];
tum_render.title = "Turan";
tum_render.description = "Turan'ın websitesi";

//left the queries seperatly
var rastgeleQuery = "SELECT baslik,hit FROM icerik ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
var son5Query = "SELECT baslik,hit FROM icerik LIMIT 5";

var query_arr = [rastgeleQuery, son5Query];
var query_name = ['rastgele', 'son5'];

//and the functions are

//query for db
function runQuery(query_arr,sira){
    connection.query(query_arr[sira], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var obj = [];
        obj[query_name[sira]] = rows;
        sonuclar.push(obj);
        if (query_arr.length <= sira+1){
            sonuc();
        }else{
            runQuery(query_arr, sira+1);
        }
    });
 }

//the function joins some functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454295/javascript-concatenate-properties-from-multiple-objects-associative-array
function collect() {
      var ret = {};
      var len = arguments.length;
      for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        for (p in arguments[i]) {
          if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            ret[p] = arguments[i][p];
          }
        }
      }
      return ret;
}

//runQuery callback
function sonuc(){
        for(var x = 0; x<=sonuclar.length-1; x++){
            tum_render = collect(tum_render,sonuclar[x]);
        }
    console.log(tum_render);
    res.render('index', tum_render);
}
```