# How to store `returned value` of function from an sql query into a variable in Node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I tried to use async and promises in order to fix this error. But still I am not able to fix it.There are two files `index.js` and `db.js` in backend. 
`db.js` is the file which has the class with all the CRUD type methods in it.
`index.js` is using that class object and sending the result to frontend. 
Here is the error part in the code. 
Inside `index.js`

```js
  socket.on("login", (User) => {
    console.log(User);
    let usersLoading = db.sign_in(User);
    console.log("UserLoading is... \n", usersLoading);
    socket.emit("UsersLoading", usersLoading);
  });
```

Inside `db.js`

```js
  async sign_in(user) { // this is the async method
    let fquery =
      "select * from Users where (Username = '" +
      user.Username +
      "'and Password = '" +
      user.Password +
      "')";
    let response = [];
    await this.con.query(fquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (result.length == 0) {
          response.push({
            Condition: "empty",
          });
        } else {
          response.push({
            Condition: "notempty",
          });
          response.push(result[0]);
        }
      }
    });
    return response; // I am trying to send the query response back to index.js file.
  }
```

User value in inxed.js is :

```json
{
  Username : "xyz",
  Password : "abc"
}
```

Actually the query part is working correctly but it is not able to store the value in 'response' variable. I also tried to do this after [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156517/how-to-store-value-from-an-sql-query-to-a-variable-in-node-js) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100184/how-to-save-the-result-of-mysql-query-in-variable-using-node-mysql)
but unfortunately I was not able to solve this issue.

Comment: It seems you’re trying to use await on a function which takes a callback. This won’t work. Instead try “promisifying” the query function first?

Comment: @evolutionbox , I even tried to put `this.con.query` inside promise. But the promise was showing <pending>

Comment: May you share that too?

Comment: ok, I am trying to do this once again, if I will get any answer, I will share. I somewhat understood how to solve this problem.