# Find and replace an element in a multidimensional JS Array w/o mutating the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
[ [ {Obj}, {Obj}, {Obj} ], [ {Obj}, {Obj}, {Obj} ] ... ]
```

And  I have an incoming Object which should replace one of the Objects in the array. I can find an Object I want to replace with a for loop, using `id` property and replace it directly:

```
  function findObject(arr, target) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j].id === target.id)
          arr[i][j] = target;
        }
    }
  }

  findObject(arr, target);
  // do stuff with arr
```

How can I achieve the same results without mutating the original array, preferably returning new array with merged object within one function?

Here is the js fiddle for convenience: https://jsfiddle.net/tnpxh8fy/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454295/how-to-concatenate-properties-from-multiple-javascript-objects

Comment: What browsers are you supporting?

Comment: @acbabis only latest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.map`, which creates a new array:

```
function findObject(arr, target) {
  return arr.map(function(users) {
    return users.map(function(user) {
      if (user.id === target.id) {
        return target;
      } else {
        return user;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some copying will do the trick:

```
findObj = function(arrArrObj, needle) {
  var ret = Array.from(arrArrObj)
  for (let i in ret)
    for (let j in i)
      if (ret[i][j].id === needle.id) {
        ret[i] = Array.from(ret[i]) // as needed
        ret[i][j] = needle
        // break
      }
  return ret
}
```

Comment: Wait, doesn't `var ret = new Array(arrArrObj)` just wrap the original array to a new array?

Comment: @jehna1, yeah, that what happens.

Comment: @jehna1 Oops! Edited.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 sorry, missed your nested `Array.from`, this should actually work just fine. Could you make a small edit so I can change my downvote to an upvote?