# How to combine objects into one object in a loop

Tags: javascript, object

I have individual objects like:

```
Object {au: Object}
Object {eu: Object}
Object {fr: Object}
```

etc

How do I combine them so they look like this:

```
Object {au: Object, eu: Object, fr: Object, uk: Object, us: Object}
```

I have the data in a for loop like so:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < storesListArray.length; ++i) {
     var storeListArray = storesListArray[i];
     for(var j = 0; j < storeListArray.length; ++j) {
         console.log(storeListArray[j]);
     }
 }
```

Any help one the best way would be awesome thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate properties from multiple JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454295/how-to-concatenate-properties-from-multiple-javascript-objects)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would begin by using the [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the elements of the array.

If you're willing to use jQuery, the [jQuery.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) can be very useful in copying objects.

```js
var storesListArray = [
 {en: {a: "something", b: "something else"}},
 {fr: {a: "something", b: "something else"}},
 {au: {a: "something", b: "something else"}}
]

var ans = {};
storesListArray.forEach(function(element){
  $.extend(true, ans, element);
 })

console.log(ans);

console.log("en:");
console.log(ans.en);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get    Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object} I need the keys to be the codes

Comment: "keys to be the codes", as in `ans.en` should return the object with keys `a` and `b`?

Comment: var storeMapping = {};
        storesListArray.forEach(function(element){
            element.forEach(function(key){
                jQuery.extend(true, storeMapping, key);
            });
        });

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for getting a single object with the parts of the array.

```js
var array = [{ au: {} }, { eu: {} }, { fr: {} }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```js
var list = [
 {en: {a: "something", b: "something else"}},
 {fr: {a: "something", b: "something else"}},
 {au: {a: "something", b: "something else"}}
]

var bigObj = list.reduce(function (o, n) {
  for (var key in n) o[key] = n[key];
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(bigObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery.extend to merge several objects into one. The first parameter is the target object and the following parameters are the ones you want to add to the target:

```
 var oAll = $.extend({},objA, objB, objC ... )
```