# convert object into array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have data coming from API, in a format like:

```
this.userSkills = [
    {
        skill_level: {
            skill: {
                id: 1,
                proficiency: "Beginner",
                name: "Core Java"
            }
        }
    },
]
```

I want to map them into objects to be like:

```
[
    {skillId: 1, skillProficiency: "Beginner", skillName: "Core Java"},
    {skillId: 7, skillProficiency: "Intermediate", skillName: "ReactJs"},
    {skillId: 2, skillProficiency: "Beginner", skillName: "Javascript"},
    {skillId: 27, skillProficiency: "Intermediate", skillName: "Common behavioral "},
    {skillId: 29, skillProficiency: "Beginner", skillName: "iOS"},
    {skillId: 34, skillProficiency: "Beginner", skillName: "API Testing"}
]
```

Which by using `map` operator I have tried to convert them into objects, like:

```
this.userSkills.map(value => { 
    const data = { 
        skillId: value.skill_level.skill.id, 
        skillProficiency: value.skill_level.proficiency, 
        skillName: value.skill_level.skill.name }; 
    const test = [] test.push(data); 
    console.log(test) 
});
```

like this, but I want them as an array of objects so that I can loop over them, how can I convert them into array of objects?

Comment: you may declare and empty array and use push method to form array of objects

Comment: I didn't get it; you already converted them into array by using map?

Comment: i tried but 

      this.userSkills.map(value => {
        const data = {
          skillId: value.skill_level.skill.id,
          skillProficiency: value.skill_level.proficiency,
          skillName: value.skill_level.skill.name
        };
        const test = []
        test.push(data);
        console.log(test)
      });

[{…}]
0: {skillId: 1, skillProficiency: "Beginner", skillName: "Core Java"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
[{…}]
[{…}]

but this is how it is coming

Comment: @nimeresam i converted them into objects

Comment: Please Refer below link. [Combined Multiple Object Into Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454295/how-to-concatenate-properties-from-multiple-javascript-objects)

Comment: @Vishal I think he wants to map list of objects into another format

Comment: Not sure why this question got so many upvotes :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood from you; you tried this?

```
this.userSkills.map(value => { 
    const data = { 
        skillId: value.skill_level.skill.id, 
        skillProficiency: value.skill_level.proficiency, 
        skillName: value.skill_level.skill.name }; 
    const test = [] test.push(data); 
    console.log(test) 
});
```

Correct me if I'm wrong?

If yes, your problem is with `test`, because it's scooped inside `map` function.

`map` function already return a new converted array, check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

try this:

```
this.newArr = this.userSkills.map(value => 
    ({ 
        skillId: value.skill_level.skill.id, 
        skillProficiency: value.skill_level.proficiency, 
        skillName: value.skill_level.skill.name
    })
);
```

And use `newArr` in `ngFor`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dataInObject = {}; // Your data here
const dataArray = Object.keys(dataInObject).map(index=>dataInObject[index]);
console.log(dataArray);
```