# Javascript - Array of maps to map

Tags: javascript, performance

I have the following array:

```
const result = [{ "1": { status: "ok" }, "2": { status: "ok" } }, { "3": { status: "error" } }]
```

And I want to convert it to a linear map, like this:

```
{ "1": { status: "ok" }, "2": { status: "ok" }, "3": { status: "error" } }
```

In an efficient way.

Currently I was doing

```
let tickets = {};
result.forEach(e => {
  tickets = { ...tickets, ...e }
});
```

which supposes re-creating the map multiple times, with the spread syntax.

Any ideas to achieve the same behavior with a lower cost?

Comment: Based on your question... `result` is an `array` with a single object, and your expected result is a single object. So you can do `const expectedResult = result[0]`. And you get what you want.

Comment: @Pipe there are 2 objects

Comment: @Pipe `result` has two objects... look between "2" and "3". @Raul - what do you mean by _lower cost_? Is what you are doing not performant enough? You could use `.reduce` instead of `.forEach`

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ....result)`

Comment: @Raul My bad, didn't notice that. Thank you. then VLAZ comment is the correct answer

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060553/)