# How to group array of object by key value pairs using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just started learning JavaScript, I have this type of array, how I can turn this array of objects into key-value pairs like below, Any source and reference is acceptable.

**Sample Array:**

```
[
  {Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1},
  {Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1}
]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
  "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb":1, 
  "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb":1
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate properties from multiple JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454295/how-to-concatenate-properties-from-multiple-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array.prototype.Reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr = [{Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1},{Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1}];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { Id, qty }) => ({ ...acc, [Id]: qty }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, a little more beginner friendly.

```
const arr = [
  {Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1},
  {Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1}
];

const newObject = {}; // empty object

// loop over each element of the array
arr.forEach(element => {
  // the key is the element identifier (Id) and the value is the element quantity (qty)
  newObject[element.Id] = element.qty;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and add the ***item.Id*** as the **key** and the ***item.qty*** as the **value** in an empty object.

```js
let arr = [{Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1},{Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1}]

let obj = {}
arr.forEach(item => {   
   obj[item.Id] = item.qty   
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in a single line of code.

```js
const arr = [
  { Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1 },
  { Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1 },
];

const result = {};

arr.forEach(({ Id, qty }) => (result[Id] = qty));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result with below code

```js
//input array
const arrList = [
  {Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1},
  {Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1}
]

function findArray(arr) {
     //define a new array to store Id's
     let newArray = [];
     //iterate through array items
     arr.forEach(item => {
         newArray.push(item.Id);
    });

   return newArray;
}

//call findArray function to get desired output
console.log(findArray(arrList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const
  array = [{ Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1 }, { Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1 }],

  object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(({ Id, qty }) => [Id, qty]));

console.log(object);
```

or, for some fragile novelty...

```js
const
  array = [{ Id: "6d7e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1 }, { Id: "6d2e75e6-c58b-11e7-95-ac162d77eceb", qty: 1 }],
  
  object = Object.fromEntries(array.map(Object.values));

console.log(object);
```